# Setup Url for Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We configured Setup Url for our Marketplace application. And it works! Marketplace redirects user to Setup Url after app installation:

1. But can we rely on it? Will marketplace use it for all installations? Does google recommends to use it?
2. Where we can find documentation for it? What special params(like ${DOMAIN_NAME}) we can use in url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information about the Setup URL is available in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/practices#8_use_the_setup_link_in_the_sdk):

> If the admin has not completed these additional setup steps and a user tries to access the application, they should be presented a graceful and meaningful failure case. For example: "Hello! Your domain administrator needs to set up this application before you can use it. Please encourage them to do so!"

The [${DOMAIN_NAME} parameter](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing#about_app_extensions) is the only one available.

Comment: The provided urls do not work or the linked page does not contain the referenced information. Could you update the urls? Is your answer still valid?